# Variable losing its value (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, cocoa, sdk, touch

I declare a variable in the header file and synthesize it in the implementation.  When the view loads (ViewDidLoad) I read a plist file an populate the variable with a value.  WIth my NSLog I see that the variable contains the value.  However, after the view loads, I have some interaction with the user via a button the executes a method.  WIthin that method I check the value again and it is invalid.  Why won't the variable maintain its value after the initial load?

program.h

```
....
NSString * user_title;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *user_title;
```

program.m

```
@synthesize user_title;

-(void)viewDidLoad{

    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    user_title = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    [array release];
}
    ....


-(IBAction)user_touch_screen:(id)sender
 {
    user_label.text = user_title;  //user_title has an invaliud value at this point
   ....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`user_title = [array objectAtIndex:0]` doesn't retain the variable.

Use this instead:

```
self.user_title = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

That will use the setter that you synthesized, and will retain the value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to retain the value you get out of the array.